# Difference of HP network adapter types?

Tags: networking, hardware, hp, hp-proliant

HP have a special type of cards they call FlexibleLOM, and I can't figure out what the differences are of the following

- [HP Ethernet 10Gb 2-port 530FLR-SFP+ Adapter](http://www8.hp.com/emea_middle_east/en/products/oas/product-detail.html?oid=5194832)
- [HP Ethernet 10Gb 2-port 560FLR-SFP+ Adapter](http://www8.hp.com/emea_middle_east/en/products/oas/product-detail.html?oid=5360658)

and

- [HP Ethernet 10Gb 2-port 530SFP+ Adapter](http://www8.hp.com/emea_middle_east/en/products/oas/product-detail.html?oid=5274086)
- [HP Ethernet 10Gb 2-port 560SFP+ Adapter](http://www8.hp.com/emea_middle_east/en/products/oas/product-detail.html?oid=5283369)

**Questions**

What do I get from going from 530 to 560?

What is the difference of FLR-SFP+ and SFP+?

Comment: Different chipsets. Broadcom, Qlogic, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In doing some research, FLR-SPF+ is different because the actual module is "modular" instead of embedded on the board. Because of this, you can swap out the connection types as needed (Ethernet, Fiber, etc) without having to consume additional PCI ports. Starting with Gen 8, the servers come with one of these modules.

As for the 530/560 differences, HP doesn't give out detailed specs of these cards. I can only assume that the 560 has the edge features and performance-wise since it appears to be using a newer chip.

Answer (score 2):

HP Ethernet 10Gb 2-port 530FLR-SFP+ Adapter is a flexibleLOM adapter, while the HP Ethernet 10Gb 2-port 530SFP+ Adapter is a standalone PCIe adapter.