# difference between FLR-SFP+ and SFP+?

Tags: networking, hp, hp-proliant

What is the difference between FLR-SFP and SFP+?

For example what is the difference between cards HP 570SFP+ and HP 570FLR-SFP+?

Which one it's better to buy?

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/586422/difference-of-hp-network-adapter-types

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The "FLR" stands for [FlexibleLOM Rack](http://www8.hp.com/h20195/v2/GetPDF.aspx%2F4AA4-6708ENW.pdf)... And "LOM" means "LAN-on-motherboard". So the FLR is really a modular motherboard-attached NIC that does not consume a PCIe slot.

Gen8 ProLiant's have one slot. I believe the Gen9's have two slots. So if you want your 10GbE to be in PCIe form-factor, get the  HP 570SFP+. If you want it on the "motherboard", use the FLR adapter.

Comment: thanks, but what is better to use PCIe form factor, or FLR?

Comment: I can't tell you that. That's up to you and what else you need to install inside of these servers.

Comment: Ed, the Gen9 DL360/380 has a non-removable 4 x 1Gbps copper module AND a FlexLOM port

Comment: @Chopper3 Good. I couldn't tell from the photos... I'm surprised they're finding room inside the servers for all of this.